# RFC822 Message-Id in GmailApi send

Tags: gmail, gmail-api

while reading mail using GmailApi, there is unique "Message-Id" (RFC822 Message-Id) field with each mail.
When I send mail using GmailApi there is no "Message-Id", if there is I couldn't find. Response message include "data" filed witch have this.
`{ id: '163924a3ddf18bd5',
   threadId: '163924a3ddf18bd5',
   labelIds: [ 'UNREAD', 'SENT', 'INBOX' ] }`
and bunch of other details.

My question is, is there any "Message-Id" in case of send mail too, and if it is how can i get it. And I am using nodeJs library

Comment: I'm having the same problem. did you find a way to get it?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what kind of ID you're looking for but the response [id](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages#resource) from the docs states that:

> **id**  *string*  The immutable ID of the message.

Comment: I am talking about RFC822 Message-Id, Updated my qus too.